# How to write a nspredicate to get records that contains part of the search term?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

How do i write a predicate to filter out data with a search string like this.

Users enters "red pepper".

This should return all the records including, "red pepper", "red bell pepper" etc

This is what i have written.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(ingredientName contains[c] %@)" ,self.searchIngrediants.text ];
        [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
```

This only returns records that contains the search term such as "red pepper", "belgian red pepper".

Is it possible to do this with a predicate. Im using Objective-c.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: But what about "red hot chili with specks and stripes pepper"? Step 1: Define in very exact terms (e.g. a regular expression) when you want a match.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. it should return such records as well.  Can you please point me to a example on how to get this done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that you need to use `LIKE`.

```
NSString *searchStringWithPattern = [self.searchIngrediants.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"*"];
searchStringWithPattern = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"*%@*", searchStringWithPattern];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(ingredientName LIKE[cd] %@)" , searchStringWithPattern];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. However this only returns me records that are named red pepper. Also only returns data when the entire search term is typed. eg: typing "red pep" gives nothing, unless type it all the way "red pepper". any idea?

Comment: @SachinthanaAluvihare Check the edited answer I have added `searchStringWithPattern = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"*%@*", searchStringWithPattern];` for that

Comment: Thank you so much! definitely saved me a lot time.. Have a good day.

Comment: @SachinthanaAluvihare Welcome mate :)

Answer (score 0):

With regular expression it should be something like:

```
NSString*    regex     = @"red.*pepper";
NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(ingredientName MATCHES %@)", regex];
```

If your input has newlines/TABs/... adapt the `regex` accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Objective C Code:-

```
NSPredicate *predicate;
predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ingredientName contains[cd] %@",self.searchIngrediants.text];
```

Contains will check the character is there or not.

Swift Code :-

```
var predicate: NSPredicate?
predicate = NSPredicate(format: "ingredientName contains[cd] %@", searchIngrediants.text)
```